# Text view not being populated with text after calling method and moving to a view controller with the same button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am trying to let my iOS app pull from a text file on a server and display it in a Text view. This works fine if I just do this by setting the url in the viewDidLoad method. But if I do it the way I need to, a button click calls a method that sets the url based on which button is clicked and then populates the Text view also while moving to the view controller, then the Text view does not receive any text.

I am not really sure if this has anything to do with it but could it possibly be because I am using one button that has both a triggered segue to move to the next view controller and then a sent event in order to pull the information? Could it be doing it out of order or something?

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "STTwitter.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    STTwitterAPI *twitter;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *scheduleText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tweetText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mScrollView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //pull from server to populate schedule
    //[self pullInfo:(1)];

    //load tweets
    //[self callTwitter];

    //set scroll view size
    _mScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 300);

}//end viewDidLoad

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}//end didReceiveMemoryWarning

- (void) pullInfo: (int) page
{//pull information from server
    NSError* err;
    NSURL* url = nil;

    if (page == 1)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu    /aecschedule1.txt"];
    else if (page == 2)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule2.txt"];
    else if (page == 3)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule3.txt"];
    else if (page == 4)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule4.txt"];
    else if (page == 5)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule5.txt"];
    else if (page == 6)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule6.txt"];
    else if (page == 7)
       url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule7.txt"];
    else if (page == 8)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule8.txt"];
    else if (page == 9)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule9.txt"];
    else if (page == 10)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule10.txt"];
    else if (page == 11)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule11.txt"];
    else if (page == 12)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule12.txt"];
    else if (page == 13)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule13.txt"];

    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    //retrieve the text if there was no reading error
    if (err != nil)
        printf("Error retrieving text");
    else
    {
        [_scheduleText setAttributedText:attrString];
        [_scheduleText sizeToFit];
        [_scheduleText setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }//end else
}//end pullInfo

- (IBAction)settingsClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"McK AEC" message:@"Developed by: Sean Boehnke" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {}];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}//end settingsClicked

- (IBAction)time1Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(1)];
}//end time1Clicked

- (IBAction)time2Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(2)];
}//end time2Clicked

- (IBAction)time3Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(3)];
}//end time3Clicked

- (IBAction)time4Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(4)];
}//end time4Clicked

- (IBAction)time5Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(5)];
}//end time5Clicked

- (IBAction)time6Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(6)];
}//end time6Clicked

- (IBAction)time7Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(7)];
}//end time7Clicked

- (IBAction)time8Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(8)];
}//end time8Clicked

- (IBAction)time9Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(9)];
}//end time9Clicked

- (IBAction)time10Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(10)];
}//end time10Clicked

- (IBAction)time11Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(11)];
}//end time11Clicked

- (IBAction)time12Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(12)];
}//end time12Clicked

- (IBAction)time13Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(13)];
}//end time13Clicked

@end
```

Comment: 1. always try to post as little code as possible. 2. Have you made sure that the URL actually returns the valid data? 3. Try to set the background color of the textView to see if the frame is properly set or not.

Comment: @iosDev82 Yes it returns data. As I said in the post, if I just call the pullInfo method directly from the viewDidLoad method then it comes up fine. That is why I feel like I am having an issue with having it move to a view controller and call a separate method at the same time.

Comment: Question not clear. I can see many timeclicked action but none performing segue. Or this viewcontroller is the one which is segued and data not populating in the textview?

Comment: @UttamSinha I am using storyboards and this is the only file I have edited any code in. I just need each button to pull from different urls and populate the text view on the next view controller that I move to from the storyboard.

Comment: @saboehnke - If this is the case then define property nstring in the next view controller and import next viewcontroller in the first one, take instance and when you segue to the next viewcontroller assign fetched data to nsstring.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your description of the issue and your comments there're a few fundamental things that are wrong here. First and foremost, the reason why this will not populate data on your pushed viewController is because you are setting the attributed text on scheduleText which is an instance variable on ViewController. If you are pushing another viewController after those buttons are pressed, then it makes perfect sense that the controller you're pushing would not have this data set because you didn't set it there, you set it on the previous controller. This data has no reason to assume you actually meant to pass it forward. That's just simply not what you asked it to do. If your intent is to pass the data forward, and you have your heart set on storyboard segues you will need to implement prepareForSegue and expose a property you can use to configure the new viewController as it's being prepared for presentation.

Sorry for the wall of text, but this is my recommendation to get through this.

First step, on your storyboard, give all of your buttons hooked up to segues button tags in the preferences tab of the right pane of interface builder. You should tag them 1 through 13 (tradition says start at 0 but this will make the next step simpler for our purposes.)

Next, get rid of all those IBActions for the buttons. We aren't going to need them anymore and they're cluttering your class. **You MUST also unhook them in your storyboard after you delete the methods or your app will crash with an error that says "this class is not key value coding-compliant"**

Next you need to implement the method -prepareForSegue on your viewController to do the rest of your heavy lifting

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSAttributedString *attrString;

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        NSUInteger seguePageNumber = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
        attrString = [self pullInfo:seguePageNumber];
    }

    YourViewControllerClass *vc = (YourViewControllerClass*)[segue destinationViewController];
    vc.attributedTextPropertyIExposed = attrString;
    //This property needs to be exposed in the new VC's header file. Once the new controller presents you can then use this property to set the string the way you want.
}
```

As a bonus, here's a pull info method that I referenced above that I find much easier to read.

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pullInfo:(NSUInteger)pageNumber
{
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mckendree.edu/aecschedule%lu.txt", (long)pageNumber];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    return attrString;
}
```

Comment: If this is the case why am I able to pull the information and display it correctly if I just call the pullInfo method directly in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Because you are setting the property on the currently visible viewController if you call it on viewDidLoad. If you present another view controller, the one where you just set the text is already buried under the newly presented controller. It's probably working but no longer visible.

Comment: Ok but either way the text is being displayed in a different view controller. I guess this is why I am not understanding.

Comment: is there a way to do this since both view controllers I am dealing with are both under the same custom class name? I mean with that being said it just confuses me more with why I need to have a reference to the next view

Comment: If you present a new view and you have no way of accessing it or its properties, there is nothing you can do to configure it or populate data based on actions in the previous controller. You need to either set the property explicitly on the controller about to be presented or figure out a way for the controller to configure itself before presentation. Setting a property on the presenting view controller and then immediately presenting another will have absolutely no effect on the next controller and bury the results. You're essentially setting properties on a thing that doesn't exist anymore.